# Information required on RoHS Declaration Class( & Exception 7A) for MOSFET NVTFS5C471NLWFTAG

Tags: mosfet, rohs

I need clarification regarding ROHS compatibility of NVTFS5C471NLWFTAG(n-Channel MOSFET).

Document given by onsemi says
[image: NVTFS5C471NLWT ROHS 1st page]

[image: Manufacturing Process Information]

[image: ROHS Exception INformation full]

Now, I need to confirm this ROHS compliant or not?

Because the exception calls for
“Lead in high melting temperature type solders(i.e. lead based solder alloys containing 85% by weight or more lead)."

If we use the Lead-free assembly process, whether this component can be accepted as ROHS complaint.

I need to get confirmation from my ASSY vendor on this.

Comment: Even if it does contain lead, you are allowed to have up to a certain percentage of lead in the assy. So you might have a’get out of jail’ card.

Answer (score 3):

In the legislation, there are 4 exemptions that can be granted when the substitutions/solutions are

- Scientifically and/or practically not applicable or not feasible, or
- The negative impacts to environment/health/safety is negligible against the benefits.

The exemption you marked is one of those 4.

It indicates that during the manufacturing of the component *(the NMOS in your case but could be an IC or any chip-type component that contains a substrate)* lead-based solder (having at least 85% by weight) is used at chip level by the manufacturer. This is under exemption and therefore allowed because the alternative processes were possibly impractical for the manufacturer.

The component is still RoHS-compliant even with having lead-based solder at chip level. So this doesn't concern you. But you still should follow lead-free soldering process requirements.